# Making a Ball class

Tags: java, class, bounce

I am back with another question about my bouncing ball applet. I have to make a class for the balls so you can easily add more. The problem is: What do I put in my class? Just an x, a y and a radius or is there more to it?

This is all of my code (with dutch comments, don't pay attention to them :))

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class BallApplet2 extends Applet implements Runnable 
{ 
  // de positie van de rode bal op de x-as en y-as en zijn straal
 int x_pos1 = 150; 
 int y_pos1 = 301;
 int radius1 = 20; 
 // de positie van de blauwe bal op de x-as en y-as en zijn straal
 int x_pos2 = 250; 
 int y_pos2 = 301; 
 int radius2 = 20;

 // de (willekeurige) snelheid van de rode bal wordt hier berekend
 int randomspeed1 = (int )(Math.random() * 7 + 2);

 // de (willekeurige) snelheid van de blauwe bal wordt hier berekend
 int randomspeed2 = (int )(Math.random() * 7 + 2);

 // het getal dat hierboven is berekend wordt toegewezen aan ballspeedx1
 private float ballspeedx1 = -randomspeed1;   

 // het getal dat hierboven is berekend wordt toegewezen aan ballspeedx2
 private float ballspeedx2 = randomspeed2;   



  public void init() {} 

  // de Thread wordt hier aangemaakt
  public void start() { 
  Thread th = new Thread (this); 
  th.start (); } 
  public void stop() {} 
  public void destroy() {} 

  // de Thread wordt hier uitgevoerd door de methode run()
  public void run () {
  //  de prioriteit van de Thread wordt verlaagd zodat hij niet nog een keer geactiveerd wordt  tijdens het uitvoeren
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
while (true) 
{ 
  x_pos1 += ballspeedx1;

  x_pos2 += ballspeedx2;


  // repaint() update de positie van de ballen
  repaint();
  // als x_pos < 100 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (x_pos1  < 100) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1; 
    x_pos1 = 100; 
  } 
  if (x_pos2  < 100) {
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2; 
    x_pos2 = 100; 
  }  
  // als x_pos > 300 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (x_pos1  > 300) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1; 
    x_pos1 = 300; 
  } 
  if (x_pos2  > 300) {
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2; 
    x_pos2 = 300; 
  }
  // als de positie van de blauwe bal (x_pos2) - de positie van de rode bal (x_pos1) kleiner is 
  // dan de som van de stralen van de rode en de blauwe bal draaien beide ballen om.                                     
  if (Math.abs(x_pos2-x_pos1)<radius1+radius2){
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }

  try { Thread.sleep (20); } 



  catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); }} 

 public void paint (Graphics g) {


// de rode bal
g.setColor (Color.red); 
g.fillOval (x_pos1 - radius1, y_pos1 - radius1, 2 * radius1, 2 * radius1); 

// de blauwe bal
g.setColor (Color.blue); 
g.fillOval (x_pos2 - radius2, y_pos2 - radius2, 2 * radius2, 2 * radius2); 


g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawLine(80,280,80,320); // lijn links
g.drawLine(320,280,320,320); // lijn rechts
g.drawLine(80,320,320,320); // lijn onder



 }  
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean more balls? I have to have 3 balls and a Ball class, I can't just add a third ball in the applet and be done with it.

Comment: No, I mean do you need more attributes?

Answer (score 1):

One of the main strengths of object orientation is the ability to group the data and logic together. Make all those properties private and add a `bounce()` method to the ball itself (parameterized with whatever arguments you need). Then you can simply instantiate 3 balls and have them bounce on their own:

```
final Ball ball1 = new Ball(150, 301, 20);
ball1.bounce();
```

Then you can add other functionality like: `Ball.collidesWith(Ball other)` to make the main logic easy to read and implement.

Read more about [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

When you design a class, you put in properties which you need now. If `x`, `y` and a `radius` is enough for your class so you can work with it, you are fine. You don't need to think of all possible attributes which you *might* need somewhen.

E.g. when you find out you need a `color` after a few days, add it. As easy as that.

However, your

```
  // de positie van de rode bal op de x-as en y-as en zijn straal
 int x_pos1 = 150; 
 int y_pos1 = 301;
 int radius1 = 20; 
 // de positie van de blauwe bal op de x-as en y-as en zijn straal
 int x_pos2 = 250; 
 int y_pos2 = 301; 
 int radius2 = 20;
```

Are good canditates to be grouped into a *seperate* ball class.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. Now how do I create a ball from that class in my applet?

Comment: If you don't know how to create classes in Java, it might be worth to do some [tutorials](https://www.google.at/search?q=java+oop+example) and read about this topic.